# USB EC vs PIC MCU

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb, microchip, usb-hub

I'm trying to make a peripheral with an embedded USB hub, which will include USB-C 3.1. As I've been researching USB I've found that Microchip has a whole slew of embedded controllers dedicated to USB, like [USB5926](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB5926), but then I've also seen most projects and tutorials use a PIC micrcontroller for a hub. Why would I use one over the other?

*Note I will be using a separate chip either way for the USB hub, just for quantity of ports.

Comment: This is far too broad a question to fit within the mission of this site.  Questions here need to be *specific* and *specifically answerable*, "Why would I use one over the other?" is neither.

Comment: I am sure there is no possibility to make a USB hub, even USB 1.1, using PIC micro-controller. Would you care to provide any links?

Comment: The post specifically says that the hub functionality is being provided by a separate chip, ie, not the MCU.  Hence the MCU would be *a downstream device hanging off the hub* and does not need to use any more recent USB standard than is needed to enable whatever limited communication need it has *on its own behalf*.

Comment: As for the USB5926, that is a hub, not a microcontroller.  You'd choose between that and other ways of building the hub aspect.  And for the peripheral aspect, you still need to chose a USB-enabled MCU, USB-enabled ASIC or USB-enabled *something* to implement the peripheral-ness.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, OP wrote, "use a PIC micrcontroller for a hub" - how it is not meant to provide "hub functionality"?

Comment: That was presumably bad phrasing, the key point is that they wrote on a line all by itself **"Note I will be using a separate chip either way for the USB hub, just for quantity of ports."**

Comment: Also this is effectively just a problematic restatement of the asker's earlier closed question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414551/what-controllers-are-necessary-for-a-keyboard-with-usb-audio-jack-rgb-and-nkr

Comment: @ChrisStratton, "That was presumably bad phrasing" -  no, it is obviously not a problem with phraseology. The title itself "USB EC vs. PIC MCU" reflects a deep misconception. USB hubs are dedicated data transporting engines that manage data at 500 MBytes/s, using hardware SERDES blocks and providing local link management (clock/symbol locks, active power management, etc). No PIC MCU can go any closer to this kind of data rates and provide this very specific USB 3.1 link functions. Given the absence of more adequate closing category, I would support closing this question as "too broad".

Comment: Well, we can agree on closing the question at least.  The poster is going to need *both* a hub chip, and a usb MCU or peripheral chip; I believe the post indicates that, especially if you see their earlier question linked above where that that was already covered.

Answer (score 2):

The USB5926 you refer to is not an embedded controller, it is a HUB. You can't use it as 
a (standalone) processor. Hence its application domain doesn't overlap that of USB-capable micro-controllers.

- "most projects and tutorials use a PIC micrcontroller for a hub"

You should provide links for this, I guess that the project you refer to are not hubs but USB endpoints (or maybe in a few cases USB hosts).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any PIC MCUs that support USB 3.0 (or 3.1).
There'd be no point as none of them will handle 5Gbps data rates.

If you want to make a USB hub for USB 3.x (or even 2.x to be honest), you should go for a dedicated IC for that task.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question as the question explains that the hub functionality will not be provided by the MCU.  The question is not really answerable, but that means it needs to be closed, not that it is open season for non-answers